# c# adding to xml issue

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("order.xml");
        XElement root = new XElement("MenuInfo");

        foreach(DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if(dr.Selected)
            {
                root.Add(new XElement("Meal", dr.Cells["Food"].Value.ToString()));
                root.Add(new XElement("SeatID", _seat));
                root.Add(new XElement("TableID", buttonTable1.Text));
                root.Add(new XElement("Price", dr.Cells["Price"].Value.ToString()));
                doc.Element("Menu").Add(root);
                doc.Save("order.xml");
            }
        }    

        MessageBox.Show("The order has been placed.");
        Main nf = new Main();
        nf.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

It used to work and I would have an order.xml file created with the following elements and the values, but now nothing happens. It still brings up the message box saying that the order has been placed, but when I look into the xml file, nothing has been added. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: is dr selected? are there rows in your datagrid? these are the only two reasons I can see that would prevent the xml file from being created.

Comment: Well, maybe `dataGridView.Rows` is empty, or `dr.Selected` is always `false`, or there is no `doc.Element("Menu")`, or `doc.Save` fails. Have you tried stepping through the code one line at a time?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I have solved it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, the data grid may be empty. I would add validation to submitButton_Click function as such

```
if (dataGridView.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    "throw some error"
}
```

if you get past that then I would also check the XDocument to ensure there is content. Wrapping your code to show the dialog inside of another if statement. Something like this

```
if(doc.ToString().Length > 0)
{
    "Your dialog code here"
}
```